# Command for querying Redis Timeseries MRANGE

Tags: python, redis

I am trying to work out how to write the command in python to query a redis timerseries from python.

When I query redis from the redis-cli I get a response.

I run the command: `ts.mrange - + FILTER ASSET=LAPTOP` 
all works fine.

I run the following command in python:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', port='xxxxx', password='xxxxxxxxx')
r.ts().mrange('-','+','FILTER ASSET=LAPTOP')
```

I get the error

```
ResponseError: TSDB: failed parsing labels
```

Does anyone have an example of this working in python / can see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My python guru colleague solved it for anyone wanting the solution. 

The filter needs to be submitted as a list:

r.ts().mrange('-','+',['ASSET=LAPTOP'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good example in the redis-py [test cases](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/blob/428510b5786c70a26a8797b8eb33b89777132884/tests/test_timeseries.py#L268) for testMultiRange.

In short it looks like you might like something like the following:

```
r = redis.Redis()
r.ts().mrange(0, 200, filters=["FILTER_ASSET=laptop"])
```